# Как разбить строку в Oracle без использования PL/SQL?

Tags: sql, oracle, строки, plsql

Как разбить строку, не прибегая к PL/SQL? Хотя от годного примера на PL/SQL по разбитию строки и запихиванию полученных подстрок в коллекцию я бы не отказался.

На выходе строка длиной `n` и без разделителей. Требуется ее разбить на подстроки по `20` символов и вывести в столбик обычным `SELECT`ом.

Строку получаю из XML BLOB:

```
select 
  xmltype(st.request, 0).extract('//tag/@at') value
from 
  some_table st
where 
 st.guid = 'some_guid';
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Коллеги, разобрался, не совсем сам конечно, но разобрался. Вот так парсятся атрибуты и с ними потом легко можно работать:

```
with some_table as
 (select '<a><tag at="fcasd"><untag><tag at="svsa">sss</tag></untag></tag></a>' request from dual
  union all
  select '<a><tag at="dsavA"/><tag at="csa"></tag></a>' request from dual
  )
  select 
   st.*,
   xml."at"
  from 
   some_table st,
  xmltable('//tag' passing xmltype(st.request)
  columns "at" varchar2 (20) path '@at') xml;
```